# Successful CartoDB Python API call doesn't update map?

Tags: python, mapping, postgis, cartography

Using urllib to make my API call to CartdoDB (per Andrew Hill's example [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/94982/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-write-data-to-cartodb-using-python)). I'm getting a successful '200' in response, and can get the script to print out my JSON response, but my problem is the map doesn't update after making this SELECT statement. Am I missing a step in order for that to happen?

Thanks!

Ben

---

```
import urllib
import urllib2
import json

username = '[MY USER NAME]'
apikey = '[MY API KEY]'
query = 'SELECT * FROM map_census_acs2012_ct WHERE (population > 8000 AND population <= 26908)'

url = "https://[MY USER NAME].cartodb.com/api/v1/sql"

# prams object that holds our api key and query.
params = {
    'api_key' : apikey,
    'q'       : query  
}

req = urllib2.Request(url, urllib.urlencode(params))
res = urllib2.urlopen(req)
res.getcode()
```

Comment: The map itself is updated using Javascript, is it not? So, a server-side Python query will not automatically update the client-side map view.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of, but I think you're probably right...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as [John Barça](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27130526/successful-cartodb-python-api-call-doesnt-update-map#comment42775587_27130526) says, in order to properly update your map in the client-side with the new data you'll need to use the [CartoDB.js API](http://docs.cartodb.com/cartodb-platform/cartodb-js.html).

ps: I'm adding the comment as an answer in order to be able to mark it as valid.